# Proof Möbius inversion theorem without using Dirichlet convolutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I’m reading a textbook on number theory and i just finished reading möbius inversion theorem
[image]

I also read the proof and fully understand it
But I have a question though

How can I Prove möbius inversion theorem directly and without using Dirichlet convolutions.

Can someone drop a hint or give an answer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Dirichlet convolutions? It's a concept that encapsulates the sentiment of many ideas, and it has numerous convenient properties such as commutativity and associativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s mostly just a manipulation of summations. If $g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$, then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)g\left(\frac{n}d\right)&=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\sum_{d'\mid\frac{n}d}f(d')\\
&=\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{d'\mid\frac{n}d}\mu(d)f(d')\\
&=\sum_{\substack{1\le d,d'\le n\\dd'\mid n}}\mu(d)f(d')\\
&=\sum_{d'\mid n}\sum_{d\mid\frac{n}{d'}}\mu(d)f(d')\\
&=\sum_{d'\mid n}f(d')\sum_{d\mid\frac{n}{d'}}\mu(d)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Now just use the fact that

$$\sum_{d\mid m}\mu(d)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }m=1\\
0,&\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$

which follows easily from the definition of $\mu$ and the fact that $\mu$ is multiplicative, to conclude that

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)g\left(\frac{n}d\right)=f(n)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the meaning of "without using Dirichlet convolutions" is to avoid using its associative and commutative, or multiplicative properties.

Let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be arbitrary arithmetic functions such that

$$
g(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)
$$

Then we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{d|n}g(d)\mu\left(\frac nd\right)
&=\sum_{ab=n}\mu(a)g(b) \\
&=\sum_{ab=n}\mu(a)\sum_{cd=b}f(c) \\
&=\sum_{acd=n}\mu(a)f(c) \\
&=\sum_{rc=n}f(c)\color{blue}{\sum_{ad=r}\mu(a)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, the core part of our problem is to handle the blue part. Since $\mu(a)=0$ whenever $a$ is divisible by some square number $>1$, we may run the summation only on factors $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots p_k^{a_k}$ of $r$ with $a_m\in\{0,1\}$:

$$
\sum_{ad=r}\mu(a)=\sum_{a_m\in(0,1)}\mu(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots p_k^{a_k})
$$

Since $\mu(p)=-1$ for all primes, and for $a_m\in\{0,1\}$, there are exactly $\binom nt$ ways to make $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k=t$, so we arrive at this after interchanging the summation symbol

$$
\sum_{ad=r}\mu(a)=\sum_{t=0}^k(-1)^t\binom kt
$$

When $r=1$, we have $k=0$, so this evaluates to one. However when $r>1$ this becomes zero due to binomial theorem. Finally, we obtain

$$
\sum_{ad=r}\mu(a)=\begin{cases}
1 & r=1 \\
0 & r\ne1
\end{cases}
$$

Plugging this result into the blue formula, we deduce

$$
\sum_{d|n}g(d)\mu\left(\frac nd\right)=\sum_{c=n}f(c)=f(n)
$$

Thus completing the derivation.

Comment: I think $\mu(n)$ is defined as the Dirichlet inverse of $1$ so that the blue part is $0$ is by definition

Comment: @reuns You are correct, but I guess "without using Dirichlet convolutions" implies that we cannot use their algebraic properties (e.g. Dirichlet inverse).